# Software for finding syllogisms in treebank data?

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, software, logic, discourse-analysis

Is there treebank search software that can locate a [syllogism](https://isidore.co/forum/index.php?topic=6#msg14), identifying its major and minor premises and terms?

<sup>cf. Eyal Mozes, “[A Deductive Database Based on Aristotelian Logic](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/B25M2X2Z/Mozes%20-%201989%20-%20A%20deductive%20database%20based%20on%20aristotelian%20logic.pdf),” *Journal of Symbolic Computation* 7, no. 5 (May 1, 1989): 487–507.</sup>

Comment: If you can specify its form exactly, it can possibly be done. But not in general.

Comment: @jlawler Why "not in general"?

Comment: Because many syllogisms are interpreted as such by pragmatic circumstances, rather than by written form.

Comment: Does ChatGPT do what I'm asking?